# Removing localStorage file automatically in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, local-storage, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS for testing purposes. I need PhantomJS to remove all the information related to the previous session after the following command,

```
phantom.exit()
```

Actually, it does that and it removes all the cookies, cache and the history in fact. But, It does not remove the saved information for localStorage command automatically. I need to go to the default path for saving this information and remove the file manually. I am wondering if there is any automatic way for removing this file. I tested following ways but none of them worked for me.

first of all, I used the following command to set the new path for this information, but PhantomJS did not care about it and just used its previous saved information again.

```
--local-storage-path = path
```

second, I used the page.open part of PhantomJS to clear the path using following command which did not work either for me.

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using phantomJS 1.9.8 on linux x64 you can test this binary which has the localStoragePath fix included: https://github.com/PatrickHuetter/phantomjs/releases/tag/1.9.8-fixedStoragePath

If you're using phantomjs on another operating system you could checkout my fork and compile it on your plattform. https://github.com/PatrickHuetter/phantomjs/tree/localStoragePathFix

PhantomJS 2.0 already has this fix included, so you can go with the official binary if you're using the 2.0 version or newer.

Answer (score 4):

It's always good to clear localStorage after you're done with testing. You have to keep in mind that you can have multiple pages open in PhantomJS at the same time, but localStorage is only bound to a specific domain.

The `localStorage.clear();` has to be executed on the page and not in phantom context:

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    localStorage.clear();
});
```

So every time before you exit the script, you should clear the localStorage (maybe multiple times depending on how many domains you visited). Alternatively, you can try to do this at the beginning of your script/page load, but it will be hard to do it well. A page must already have a target URL, but the page cannot be yet loaded. Otherwise, the `clear` may come at a time when the page javascript already executed. Then this should probably be done only once per domain. Otherwise, navigation over different pages of a site will be broken.

---

Another simple solution would be to use the fs module to delete all localStorage files in the Ofi labs directory at the beginning of the script, but this might delete the localStorage of pages that you didn't want deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I used the command in the context of the page but, not before exiting from phantom. Thanks for your helps.